# How to change welcome splash screen on vagrant ssh?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

In some (if not all) vagrant boxes, you can see some kind of welcome text/splash ascii/text available. which can be seen when you do `vagrant ssh` into the server. How can one implement this on creating a custom vagrant box? or modifying a already created vagrant box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called MOTD, (Message of the Day).

Located in `/etc/motd`.

If you want to edit the content, use the text editor you preferred. I'm using nano.

```
sudo nano /etc/motd
```

Insert the text you need to put in, and save the file (ctrl+O in nano).

P.S: By default, `/etc/motd` is linked to `/var/run/motd` and it resets every time you login. To make permanent changes, you should first remove the current file and then create a new one. follow the below steps:

```
1. sudo rm /etc/motd
2. sudo nano /etc/motd
```

then write and save the file.